# How to call a C# static method from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've seen some articles showing how to call a C# method from JavaScript using Microsoft's [WebMethod] for a Web Forms application. I'd like to do the same with an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a C# static method that returns translated data:

```
public static string Translate(string word)
{
  return langRepo.Translate(word);
}
```

The above function works fine inside server-side code. However, I'd like to extend the same code to the client side. Ideally I would like to create a jQuery function like this:

```
function Translate(word) {
  //call C# translate method and return result
}
```

And use it like this:

```
"<hr /><h5>" + Translate(heading) + "</h5>";
```

How would I do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use ajax to call a server method

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't work

Comment: The you did not try correctly :)

Comment: add your ajax code and we would be able to correct that.

Comment: **AJAX is asynchronous**. `return t;` will immediately be executed after starting the AJAX call, but regardless of whether the call has completed or not (which means the success method has never had the chance to put anything into `t`). You need to look into using callback methods (this is a rather broad topic)

Comment: And here I thought this question was easy...

Comment: First of all, what do you see when you paste the url ".../api/translate/anyword" on to a web browser? You should get a json with translated word. In debug mode it should hit the api controller action.

Comment: When I type .../api/translate/word I get the translated word back "translated" (with quotes). The api gets hit when the ajax called is made. The problem is that I'm unable to "capture" this result and it has something to do with the nature of Asynchronous calls. My problem is that I'm treating it as a "synchronous" call which obviously it isn't.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time in my years of programming, I've had to change an AJAX call to synchronous for it to work the way I wanted it. All that was needed was to add the ***"async: false"*** attribute to the AJAX call. This way the AJAX call is treated like any other synchronous function:

```
function Translate(word) {
    var Url = "/api/translate/" + word;
    var translated;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: Url,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            translated = response.translatedWord;
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var error = CapitalizeFirst(textStatus) + ": " + errorThrown + " - " + jqXhr.responseText;
            bootbox.alert(error);
        }
    });

    return translated;
}
```

For those of you thinking of implementing this as a solution for your project, THINK AGAIN!  Making an AJAX call synchronous is no trivial matter. Doing so will force your users into waiting for a response back from the server before the program is responsive again. Unless you're sure the data set is small and its access is not very frequent, you should look for other ways.

Comment: This is absolutely not the solution you should pursue. I can't see your screenshots, but it's clear you're doing something wrong somewhere, as you're hardly the first person to call a method asynchronously using jQuery (I literally did this earlier today). Secondly, this is probably not the approach you should pursue anyway if you're looking to translate webpages.

Comment: If you have a better solution, by all means, please post it!

Comment: It has to be!! There is an Ajax call inside another Ajax call. They will all get mixed up when executed asynchronously. The inner one needs to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Add  `[WebMethod]` on top of your function in server side.
- Call from client side should be looking like the following snippet:

Hint: The type should be of type "POST". check [this](http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/01/02/calling-asp-net-code-behind-using-jquery-ajax-simple-complete-example/) for complete example.

```
function Translate(word){
  // Type of data passed should match the function's parameters
  var data = {word: word};
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pageName.aspx/Translate",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (response) {
      // Here you can assign response to tags.
      // If response was empty, try response.d.
      $("#id").html(response);

    }
  });
}
```

If you are using an ASP.NET MVC application, you can use `[HttpGet]` instead and return the result from your function (Action) as in JSON format since we specified in our Ajax request we are expecting `dataType: "json"`.

Below is an example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Translate(String word)
{
  var resultWord = ModelInit.repo.TranslateItem(word);
  return Json(new {result = resultWord}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the success handler in your Ajax call, get the value by accessing the `result` property:

```
success: function (response) {
  // Here you can assign response to tags
  $("#id").html(response.result);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. You're assuming my function is inside a ".aspx" page. I'm using MVC (No .aspx pages here). I created a Web API that "mimics" the function call but even this didn't work for me.

Comment: My function is inside another assembly I call "App.Services.Helpers":

Comment: namespace App.Services.Helpers
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static string CapitalizeFirst(string word)
        {
            // Check for empty string.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            // Return char and concat substring.
            return char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1);
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public static string Translate(string word)
        {
            return ModelInit.repo.TranslateItem(word);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Maybe I could go about this another way...  Let's say I create a Web API where I can pass the word and it will translate it for me like this: /api/translate/title and this API returns a string: "título". How can I grab this result and use it like this: heading = "<hr /><h5>" + translatedWord + "</h5>";?

Comment: your question was not clear enough as you mentioned "web forms" applications that is why I wrote this answer. if it is MVC application no need to decorate with [WebMethod] .. instead decorate with [HttpGet] and inside your function - return Json(new {id = 10, title="test"});

Comment: That still comes back as "undefined"

Comment: Whether I use "post" or "get", the function response on success is "undefined"

Comment: can you plz update your question by adding your complete server code

Comment: regarding your first question, use "get". no screenshots added, please make sure to update it again

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. First a C# controller action that will return a json and then call controller action from a jQuery method.

```
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Translate(string word) 
    {
        var translatedWord = langRepo.Translate(word);
        return Json(translatedWord, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
}
```

jQuery method:

```
function Translate(word){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Language/Translate",
        data: {word: word},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.length == 0) {
                alert("Cannot translate.");
            }
            else {
                // Get the translated word
                var translatedWord = data.translatedWord;

                // Update the DOM element (label) with translated word 
                $("#translatedWord").text(translatedWord);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your screenshots (imgur domain blocked for me) and you didn't post much of your code, so I will show you an example of how I did it, and I can update the answer to better answer your question later.

I called a stored procedure and used AJAX to insert the resulting data into my page.

First, I had an object in C# that held a start and end date. My model:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

My data access layer (`DateRepository`), which calls my stored procedure (anonymized it a bit since it's not relevant to this question):

```
public static List<DateRange> GetDates(int number)
{
    // execute stored procedure, ORM converts the rows to a list of objects
    ...
    return dateRanges;
}
```

My service layer, which calls the data access layer:

```
[Route("Dates/{number}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get_DateRanges(int number)
{
    var response = DateRepository.GetDates(number);
    return Json(response);
}
```

The `Json(result)` is from `System.Web.Http` > `ApiController` > `JsonResult<T> Json<T>(T content)`.

Now, my UI layer controller calling this service method:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Get_DateRanges(int number)
{
    var response = await ServiceClient.HttpGetList<DateRange>([url here calling /Dates/{number} ]);
    return new JsonResult { Data = response, MaxJsonLength = Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxJsonLength"]), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

And that `ServiceClient` method (simplified, omitting authorization etc details):

```
public static class ServiceClient
{
    public static async Task<List<T>> HttpGetList<T>(string url)
    {
        using (var client = SetupHttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            CheckResponse(response);

            var tList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<T>>();
            return tList;
        }

    }
}
```

Remember, this JSONResult is of `List<DateRange>`. This is what will be in the data field of the JSON.

Finally, the javascript code calling the UI controller method:

```
function updateDateRanges() {
    var nNumber = $("input#Number").val();
    var params = { number: nNumber };

    // note the JSON call is to the UI layer
    $.getJSON(ROOT + "UIController/Get_DateRanges", params, function (data) { })
    .done(function (data) {
        // change model values from server
        $("input#StartDate").val(data[0].StartDate);
        $("input#EndDate").val(data[0].EndDate);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        errorAlert("Error retrieving dates.");
    })


}
```

Note that the way I retrieve my dates (e.g. `data[0].StartDate`) is because I have a list of date range objects. Since you can call your function that returns the JSON separately (just as if I had typed in the URL for my service layer into my browser), it should be easy to see what that JSON `data` looks like.

From looking at your comments, it seems your problem is not at all what is stated in the original post, but a basic understanding of javascript's asynchronous nature. Consider the following example:

```js
$("#output").click(function() {
    var inputText = $("#output").text();
    translateWord(inputText);
});

function translateWord(word){
    getTranslationFromServer(word);
}

function getTranslationFromServer(word) {
    // using setTimeout to simulate slow response (2 seconds) instead of AJAX request
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#output").text("texto en español");
    }, 2000);

    $("#output").css('background-color', 'yellow');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output">
English text
</div>
```

Notice that even though the `setTimeout` function is called first, what happens immediately is that the background changes to yellow, and 2 seconds later, the text is translated. That is due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript. While it's waiting on your AJAX call, it has moved on to the next line. So in your particular example, you set `var t = "";`, you make your AJAX call, and the next line is to `return t;`. So while you're waiting on your AJAX call, the program has moved to the next line, which says to `return`: exit this function and return this value to the caller. So you are exiting your function before it ever has a chance to finish.

Okay, so what you're real question is: "How do I wait for this javascript function to complete before returning to the other function?" Well, I originally suggested callbacks, but the better solution these days is to use promises. Since you seem to be using jQuery, I will use their [promise library:](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

```js
$("#output").click(function() {
    var inputText = $("#output").text();
    translateWord(inputText);
});

function translateWord(word){
    $("#output").text("waiting...");
    $.when(getTranslationFromServer(word))
 .then(
     function(word) {
      $("#output").text(word);
                $("#output").css('background-color', 'orange');
     }
    
    );
}

function getTranslationFromServer(input) {
$("#output").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var output = "";
    // using setTimeout to simulate slow response (2 seconds) instead of AJAX request
    setTimeout(function(){
        // mock translate function
        if (input === "English text") {
            output = "texto en español";
        }
        else if (input === "texto en español") {
            output = "English text";
        }
        else {
            output = "No translation for this text found."
        }
        deferred.resolve(output);
        }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">English text</div>
```

I changed the background colors to hopefully help you follow along where in the code the javascript is. I believe this finally answers your XY question regarding javascript.

Comment: OK. Your solution is what I call "conventional" and is the way many of us developers do it every day. Your $.getJSON is writing out the values DIRECTLY to the DOM. BUT as you can see from the question (if you could see it) I want to know how to get the result of an AJAX call as a return value from a function that you can call in Javascript. This way, the function can be made generic (like Capitalizing the first letter) and used anywhere as needed and not just for a SPECIFIC USE CASE. Why do I need it this way? Because in this case I am calling it from INSIDE another AJAX function!

Comment: @KeithHarris My approach is beyond generic-- the data is inserted into the DOM because I'm displaying that data. That doesn't make anything any less general. If you need to call an async function from inside another one, it sounds like you need to read about how callbacks work in Javascript.

Comment: Your solution won't work for me because I don't know ahead of time what the DOM will be at run time. In fact, the DOM is built dynamically depending on what the user is allowed to access. I realize that this is an unusual case (as I've never had to do resort to this before) so I wondered if other developers out there have had a similar issue and how they solved it.

Comment: I tried using a callback function (also shown in the screenshot that you can't see) but it didn't work either.

Comment: @KeithHarris I have answered your questions with snippets demonstrating the proper way to wait on your AJAX call that should hopefully help your understanding of javascript. If you could do me a giant favor, it would be to edit your actual code into your original question, because it's a lot easier for you to copy/paste it than it is for me to re-type it from a screenshot on my phone. If you want me to actually use your code as an example, you need to post it for me.

Comment: @KeithHarris Also, please read about promises-- they will be helpful for you when you need to chain AJAX calls together, as you said in your original comment on my answer.

Comment: @KeithHarris Just pinging you again to see if you ever looked into using javascript/jQuery promises?